# How to setup luks encryption to ask for passphrase after suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend, encryption, luks

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with full disk encryption enabled, using the graphical installer. However, the system does not ask for the decryption key on resume.

Most search results on this subject seem to be at least 3 years old. Is there a modern guide, or is this something that is supposed to just 'work'?

Comment: What do you mean by resume? you want the system to ask your encryption key after waking up from suspend?  I don't think that's possible cause when you boot up everything is decrypted and while you suspend your system your files are still decrypted and many of them are available on the ram.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want. It's not true that everything is decrypted on bootup - that would require twice as much hard disk space and running an encrypted file system would have no CPU overhead.

Comment: The workflow is not as you think; anyway, *as I know* it's not possible, because while you are booting the system, it's `GRUB` and `intramfs` which came in the game to decrypt your (full encrypted) setup, but when your system is running that means your resource are busy and you can't just encrypt them on the air at the same time if it even was possible, then you have nothing (tools) available to decrypt it.

Comment: Use hibernate instead, I guess that would do the job for you cause everything will be stored on the disk and memory will be freed.

Comment: Another thing that I just remembered is `encryptfs`, I think you can use it to protect your running sessions, `luks` protects you against cold boot, however `encryptfs` is a good option for running system.

Comment: So what does `luksSuspend` and `luksResume` do? If what I want isn't possible, then these commands would seem to be useless, surely?

Comment: Let me check them ;) Have you read the man page of `cryptsetup` for these two command?  doesn't seems be related to system suspend. and it says: *WARNING: never suspend the device on which the cryptsetup binary resides.* the usage is for other devices (an other hard disk) not a full encryption.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification - think it's suspend-to-disk and not suspend-to-ram I need. Seems suspend-to-ram and encryption are (or should be) mutually exclusive options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57684/discussion-between-andrew-marshall-and-ravexina).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, because when you boot up, everything will be decrypted and while you suspend your system, your files are still available in decrypted form and many of them are available on your memory.

While you are booting-up the system, a lot of tools will be get involved to decrypt your full encrypted device (Hard disk), things like `GRUB` and `initramfs`.

However, When your system is running, that means a lot of your resource are busy and you can't just encrypt all of them on the air; At the same time, if even it was possible, then you have no more tools available to decrypt your device again.

As we can see in `cryptsetup's` man page, there are two subcommand: `luksResume` and `luksSuspend`, these two are not related to system suspend, they suspend a device; And if we pay more attention we will find an warning:

> WARNING: never suspend the device on which the cryptsetup binary resides.

Which mean it's not capable of encrypting whole system while it's running, because as I already said, it's not capable of decrypting it again.

`luks` will protect you against `cold boot` attacks, you can use Ubuntu home encrypting in contrast of `luks` to protect your home directory when you are not logged in but your machine is running.

For `luks`, you can use `hibernate` feature, because everything will be stored on hard disk and your memory will be freed. it should do the job.

Comment: Existing searches on the subject seem to indicate that home folder encryption is a _less_ secure option than whole disk encryption. However, if what you say is true, then in fact home folder encryption is _more_ secure when a laptop is in a suspended state?

Comment: It's kinda true, you can use both of them to get all the advantages at the same time.